# Check if file with name exists and than save with other name

Tags: c#, sharepoint, outlook, save, filenames

I'm currently developing an Outlook Addin which saves e-mail to sharepoint online,
but before it saves them i need to check if a file with the same name already exists so it doesn't overwrite anything, here is the method which saves the file:

```
            {
            currExplorer = OutlookApp.ActiveExplorer();
            selection = currExplorer.Selection;
            if (selection != null)
            {
                SharePointHelper spHelper = new SharePointHelper("LoginName", "Password", "Url/FolderDirectory");
                if (selection.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= selection.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var item = selection[i] as Outlook.MailItem;
                        if (item == null) 
                            continue;

                        // Check for attachments and save
                        currMail = item;

                        string fileName = String.Format("{0} - {1}.msg", SafeFileName(currMail.SenderName), SafeFileName(currMail.Subject));
                        string filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), fileName);
                        currMail.SaveAs(filePath, Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG);

                        System.Net.HttpStatusCode status = spHelper.UploadFile(filePath, fileName); 
                        if (status != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created)
                            MessageBox.Show(fileName + " failed to upload.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

since I'm a beginner I lack the experience on how to go for this,
Your help is sincerely appreciated, thanks to you all!

Comment: `if (File.Exists(filename))...`

Comment: Hi Matthew,
Does this also work on SharePoint, because I'm having some Trouble with it

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.IO.File.Exists(string path) to determine if it exists.
If it does, you can change its name and test if the new name already exists until you find something not already used.

You can see documentation on msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx

Comment: Does this also work on SharePoint, because I'm having some Trouble with it

Comment: It will work if you have the physical path of the file. ie: c:\temp\x.txt

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check against SharePoint files, you can look into using `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web` and the method `GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(string serverRelativeUrl)`
[GetFileByServerRelativeUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.getfilebyserverrelativeurl%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

[Getting sharepoint excel file from sharepoit libraries using Client object model in asp.net](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/5c9f052f-087a-4877-9b79-cf5b3d6fb2dc)

once you load the file from the library into an object you can do a `!= null` check and if the file is not null you can then change the name of the file.

Answer (score -1):

use `System.IO.File.Exists(string path)`